# RabbitMQ and Python 3: How to consume message from different queues with priority

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, queue, pika

I have two types of tasks task1 and task2; also I have two types of consumers ConsumerA and ConsumerB.

ConsumerA can process only tasks type task1. ConsumerB can process both types of tasks: task1 and task2.

I want the ConsumerA to process only tasks type task1.

I want the ConsumerB to process tasks type task2 first and process tasks type task1 only when there is no tasks type2.

How to design this solution with RabbitMQ. I think about using two queues, but I don't know how to ensure that it processes tasks type2 only when there are no tasks type1.

I have read all StackOverflow without any success.

Maybe someone solved this task?

Answer (score 1):

Hello @Dima Voronenkov

You may want to check [Priorities Queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html) and also [Round-robin dispatching](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html) from RabbitMQ documentation.

With both you could create one queue per worker, and distribute `task1` to both queues and to process `task2` with higher priority than `task1`.

This could be expanded further if this approach meets your requirements.

A graphic description of RoundRobin method:

[image: Ex]

*Edit 1*: To avoid `task1` piling up for *ConsumerB* you can assign to the `task1` a [time to live](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) so when they "expire" and send them to a "dead-letter-queue", that actually points to ConsumerA queue, so when ConsumerB is busy, those `task1` messages will be redirected to the other queue.

Going beyond, you can also give "more tickets" to *ConsumerA* queue, at least in RR standard definition, I do not know how to do it on RabbitMQ, but it can be achieved creating more *ConsumerA* like queues, to group them in the same cluster of queues.

**Approach 2**

Using Topics(check link in the bottom) and [priorities](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html) could also be a good solution, however I have not tested both on the same exercise, I can not see why it would not work, check on below image:

[image: ex2]

In this scenario, only one queue is needed with one exchange, and ConsumerA will only consume `task1` messages while ConsumerB will consume both messages giving a higher priority to `task2`.

Topics: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html

Comment: If I distribute task1 to both queues there will be duplicates. How can I avoid them?

Comment: If you use Round-Robin approach, you will have no duplicates, as exchange will send 1 message to 1st queue and the next one to the 2nd queue(if you go with default settings of course).

Comment: There will be another issue: in 2nd queue will be many task1 messages and   ConsumerB can't process them quickly (really I have 10 ConsumerA and only one ConsumerB)

Comment: @DimaVoronenkov Check latest edit, it contains a TTL approach.

Comment: @DimaVoronenkov I see your point, it was very ovearloaded, take a look on the second approach. A PoC must be done but it should work.

Comment: How can I allow ConsumerA to consume only task1 messages? If I would know how to do it, it is a solution.

Comment: Read topic sections. You need to assign a topic for each task and give a pattern to consume for each consumer. Read example of topic at the end of my answer

Comment: It is impossible as I know. I can consume messages only from a queue. (I know that I can attach queue to topics) But consumer can consume only all messages from queue, filtering is not supported as I know